# Getting immutableid of an office365/azure user for the SAML assertion

Tags: azure, office365, saml, azureportal

Looking at their documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp), it looks like we need three things in the SAML assertion.

```
NameID -    The value of this assertion must be the same as the Azure AD user’s ImmutableID

IDPEmail -  The User Principal Name (UPN) is listed in the SAML response as an element with the name IDPEmail

Issuer -    Required to be a URI of the identity provider
```

I assume idp email is just the email of the user which corresponds to `userPrincipalName` field in microsoft graph API. This we can easily fetch from the API.

I am not sure however what ImmutableID is.

Is there a way to fetch it using the microsoft's graph API? If not, how do we get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@nkpatel Yes, using Graph API, you can fetch the value for Immutable ID. In case the user object is sycned from On-Prem AD to AAD, using the AAD Connect Tool, the user object will have an attribute called "**onPremisesImmutableId**" in the Graph API response for that user.

```
Eg: GET  https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<UPN of the user>
```

The value that you wound find under this attribute "**onPremisesImmutableId**" would contain a **Base64Encoded** value. By default, the on-Prem user's **ObjectGUID** is base64Encoded and stored in the "**onPremisesImmutableId**" in Azure AD.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have the "onPremisesImmutableId" from Microsoft Graph Api if being set, using following endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayname,userprincipalname,givenname,onpremisesimmutableid
```

If it is null you can explicitly set that ImmutableId using the following powershell command.

```
Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName abc@domain -ImmutableId 123
```

Provided that the domain must not be federated one. If it is federated you have to convert that to "Managed" one.